# how to edit an item in multiselect element by double click in knockout

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, edit, multi-select

I have a list with items and want to edit only the selected item on a double click or something like that.
Is it possible to edit selected items in an multiple select list on double click by a property instead of index, like Name?
how to implement below dblclick edit event function:

```
<select multiple="multiple" height="5" 
     data-bind=" options: ItemsInDB, 
                 optionsText: 'Name', 
                 selectedOptions: selectedItems, 
                 event: { dblclick: editItem } "></select>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's doable, but since the `options` binding doesn't provide any easy access to the current item in a click handler (as far as I'm aware), you would need some post processing of the option element so that you can for example save their index in the original array in a data attribute, so that you know which item to edit later. There's an `optionsAfterRender` callback you could use for that.

```
<select multiple="multiple" height="5" 
     data-bind=" options: ItemsInDB, 
                 optionsText: 'Name', 
                 selectedOptions: selectedItems, 
                 event: { dblclick: editItem },
                 optionsAfterRender: setOptionData">
</select>
```

It's provided the option element and the data item against which it is bound, so you could do this:

```
vm.setOptionData = function (option, item) {
    option.dataset.itemIndex = vm.ItemsInDB.indexOf(item);
}
```

Then in the click handler, you can grab the index again and edit the item:

```
vm.editItem = function(data, event) {
    vm.isEditing(!vm.isEditing());
    vm.editingItem(vm.ItemsInDB()[event.target.dataset.itemIndex]);
}
```

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/thebluenile/vpu2d1c4/

Comment: can you give me a fiddle this code in javascript?